# how to use batch script to export data from oracle into excel file with column names

Tags: export-to-excel

1. This is my bat script:

   ```
   set linesize 4000 pagesize 0 colsep ','
   set heading off feedback off verify off trimspool on trimout on

   spool &1

   select *
   from siebel.s_contact;

   spool off

   exit;
   ```
2. Then I try to run below command. I can generate a `Excel` file with data but column names are missing.

   ```
   C:\Users\jy70606\Documents\Script>sqlplus -s geneos/password@database @C:\Users\jy
   70606\Documents\Script\daily.sql daily.csv
   ```
3. My question is, how to make the columns available in my `Excel`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Bat Script contains the following command to remove the columns

`set heading off`

You need to switch it on

`set heading on`

Reference: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12040.htm#i2699001